# How to Prove or Disprove Language Acceptance with Limited Error by a Non-Deterministic Turing Machine?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

Let M be a non-deterministic Turing machine (NDTM) that accepts a language L if and only if:

> - for each $ x\in L $ M doesn't accept x for at most m branch(path) calculations.
> - for each $ x\notin L $ M doesn't reject x for at most m branch calculations.

let M be a Turing machine non deterministic, with one or two options exactly for each
transition of $\delta$

**Question:**

> proof or disproof:Given these conditions, can we prove or disprove that $L\in R$ ?
> if M accepts a language L with 1 error, and for each word $x\in Sigma ^*$ in the calculation tree of M on x there at least 4 calculation paths then $L\in R$